# Ошибка при изменении application.css

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Rails 3.2.13 При изменении application.css появляется ошибка:

```
No such file or directory - /home/www.site.ru/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets%2F386e9dd0f9efdce6f92ce93a6d10720131028-2917-1kmkjg5.lock
```

Гуглить файлопровод, кэширование?

Comment: /home/www.site.ru/tmp

Это у вас пользователь такой, www.site.ru? Где у вас в принципе приложение-то лежит? И где результаты работы файлопровода?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it:

```
rake tmp:pids:clear             
rake tmp:sessions:clear
rake tmp:sockets:clear
rake tmp:cache:clear
```